# How does this CSS produce a circle when applying equal width and height?

Tags: html, css

How does this [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) produce a circle exactly applying the half of equal width/height?

```
div{
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    border-radius: 100px; 
    background-color: red;
}
```

[image: Circle with CSS]

Comment: It's a square with round corners. 4 round corners which just touch = a circle

Comment: A clear demonstration of no research effort whatsoever.  Simply mocking it up and tweaking the values would show you how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this explanation](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) and everything will be clear :)

> **How it Works**
>
> Rounder corners can be created independently using the
> four individual border-*-radius properties (border-bottom-left-radius,
> border-top-left-radius, etc.) or for all four corners simultaneously
> using the border-radius shorthand property.

Comment: Summarise the explanation in your answer, otherwise the answer becomes useless when (rarely 'if') that link dies.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your border-radius. You set it to be 100 pixels which is exactly half of the original square, so it will turn it into a circle. Try doing:

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```